# Issues using 'for' loop with rtweet::get_followers in R

Tags: r, twitter

I'd like to scrape multiple twitter user's followers using the `get_followers` function from the `rtweet` package, and I think `for` loop can help the process.

To do that, I firstly made a data frame of some twitter users (select 'screen_name').
The data frame that I made is shaped as below.

```
       > screen_name
1           xxxx
2          xxxxx
....
```

And then, I tried a `for` loop with those data, but it doesn't work. (I used the `rtweet` and the `devtools` packages.)

```r
flw <- vector("list", length(dataframe))
n <- 14872

for(i in seq_along(flw)){
  flw[[i]] <- get_followers(user = dataframe[i], n = n)
  Sys.sleep(60*15)
}
```

The following error is returned constantly:

> Error in get_followers_(user = list(screen_name = c("xxxx", "xxxxx",  :
> is.atomic(user) is not TRUE.

How can I solve the problem?

I'd sincerely appreciate any advice, feedback and clarifications.
Thanks

Comment: What if you do `user = dataframe[i, "screen_name"]`?

Comment: @slamballais Thanks a lot for your suggestion. The result comes with a new error saying _Error in get_followers_(user = NULL, n = 14872, page = "-1", retryonratelimit = FALSE,  : isTRUE(length(user) == 1) is not TRUE_..

Comment: This error suggests that something is wrong with your `dataframe`, since it says that you're inputting `NULL` to `user`. Check `str(dataframe)`, and check `table(is.null(dataframe$screen_name))`. Make sure to remove `NULL` values (and any `NA` values -> `is.na()`) before using `get_followers`.

Comment: @slamballais I fully understood. Thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

- `flw <- vector("list", length(dataframe))` would create a list of length same as number of columns but I think you need a list of length which is same as number of rows.
- `dataframe[i]` is selecting a column from the dataframe you might need `dataframe$screen_name[i]`
- You can use `lapply` or `map` functions to avoid `for` loop and initialisation of a list.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(dataframe$screen_name, function(x) {
  Sys.sleep(60*15)
  get_followers(x, n = n)
})) -> flw
```

With `map` :

```
map_df(dataframe$screen_name, function(x) {
  Sys.sleep(60*15)
  get_followers(x, n = n)
}) -> flw
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanations. They'll be so helpful. :-) BTW, what does '->' sign mean?

Comment: @ClaireJoe It is equivalent to `<-`, but everything on the left is assigned to the variable on the right.